# Кнопка запомнить в AuthenticationForm

Tags: django

Имеется такой код:

```
class LoginUserForm(AuthenticationForm):
username = forms.CharField(label='Логин', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
...
class LoginUser(DataMixin, LoginView):
form_class = LoginUserForm
template_name = 'iviolations/login.html'

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    c_def = self.get_user_context(title="Авторизация")
    return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('home')
...
 <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    
        <div class="form-error">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
        
        {% for f in form %}
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}"></label>{{ f }}
        <div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    
        <button type="submit">Войти</button>
    </form>
```

Как добавить кнопку запомнить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forms.py

```
class LoginUserForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Логин', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    ...
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField() #новый
```

views.py.

```
class LoginUser(DataMixin, LoginView):
    form_class = LoginUserForm
    template_name = 'iviolations/login.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        c_def = self.get_user_context(title="Авторизация")
        return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
       
        remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']  
        if not remember_me:
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)  
            self.request.session.modified = True
        return super(LoginUser, self).form_valid(form)
```

Это просто идея как вы можете это сделать.

в settings.py добавите это:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не подскажете еще, что сделать, что бы при попадании на страницу `/login` авторизованного пользователя перенаправляло на `/index`

Comment: какой у вас url для /index в вашем urls.py

Comment: `path('index', ContactFormView.as_view(), name='home'),`

Comment: Для ограничения не авторизованных нашел такой способ: `@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')` а вот с авторизованными не разберусь пока что

Comment: @helldrg я правил мой код посмотрите в конце.

Comment: @helldrg работает ?

Comment: Это не много другое, это после авторизации перекидывает на главную, а если вписать вручную адрес /login, то на главную не перейдет автоматически оттуда

Comment: то есть, если пользователь авторизован и пытается зайти на страницу /login, его должно редиректнуть на главную. Для функций существует такая конструкция `@login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field')` а для класса не могу найти

Comment: @helldrg вы можете обьяснить по подробнее я не понимаю хорошо по русски.

Comment: when i have status user, i input in url address 127.0.0.1/login. Open login page. I want, if i have status user redirected from /login page to /index page. Sorry for my poor and bad english =)

Comment: @helldrg я понял вac,вы можете мне показать ваш urls.py для /login ?

Comment: @helldrg допустим что это ваш url;path('login/',LoginUser.as_view(),name='login') тогда вы можете попробавать сделать это:path('login/',LoginUser.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True),name='login')

Comment: redirect_authenticated_user=True это все что вам нужно.

Comment: напишите мне если работает ?

Comment: утром смогу только сказать, спасибо большое!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает! А можно сделать, если не авторизован пользователь, то со всех страниц будет на страницу `/login` перенаправлять?

Comment: @helldrg сначала сделайте это в views.py.from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

Comment: @helldrg a потом добавите LoginRequiredMixin внутри class которые вы хотите незабудьте добавить это LOGIN_URL = 'login' в settings.py.чтобы направить пользователь в /login.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Работает!